# XAML. Access to every TextBlock inside Grid with name as variable

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

Hi everyone:) I have to get access to parameters in every TextBlock from code behind. I don't want to access so many elements directly by its name for each element, so I want to do it in loop. I have table with names of those TextBlocks.

Is this any option to change TextBlock parameter using variable as its name?

For example I want to do sth like that: (pseudo code ;) )

```
string[] names={"id1","id2","id3"} // etc.
foreach( string x in names )
// I want to change opacity in each TextBlock which name is in table 'names'
{
    x.Opacity = 50;// x used like name of TextBlock from XAML
}
```

Do you have any ideas how to do it? Or it is impossible and I have to use many nested loops to do it?

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Don't do this. 1. Learn MVVM. 2. Add `Opacity` property to your view-model, bind opacity of text blocks in your view to the property, adjust opacity of all controls by changing the property's value.

Comment: Would you mind to show me or write for me an example of this? I'll be grateful. I'm just a beginner of XAML and C#.

I think it should look like this in xaml:
`Opacity="{Binding opValue}"`and in code behind: `public string opValue( get; private set; )`

Unfortunately I don't know am I right with that or what else should i do.

Comment: You'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, set `DataContext` etc. Just google for "WPF MVVM tutorial" or look for documentation of specific MVVM libraries like Caliburn.Micro or MVVMLight. WPF is designed to work with MVVM, so you'll have to learn that sooner or later anyway (WinForms-way in WPF is painful).

Comment: I guess you're right. Unfortunately I don't have that much time to learn it now. I will do it anyway in future, couse I really want to, but for now I have to do it in this painful way ;) Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't implement MVVM yet for this case, you can use [`FindName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to find control by name :

```
string[] names={"id1","id2","id3"}; // etc.
foreach(string x in names)
{
    var txt = (TextBlock)FindName(x);
    txt.Opacity = 50;
}
```

Or if all `TextBlock`s reside in the same parent container, you can do in more efficient way using LINQ :

```
string[] names={"id1","id2","id3"};
var textblocks = parentContainer.Children
                                .OfType<TextBlock>()
                                .Where(t => names.Contains(t.Name));
foreach(TextBlock t in textblocks)
{
    t.Opacity = 50;
}
```

Comment: You can also make a recursive function to get all the elements even if they are not in the same container:
`void SetOpacityForChildren(Panel p)
{
 foreach(UIElement element in p.children)
 {
  if (element is Panel) SetOpacityForChildren(p);
  else if (names.Contains(element.Name){ opacity = 50; }
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

For MVVM, you need to specify a DataContext for your element or one of it's parents:

MainPage.xaml (note: I skip all the namespace definitions that are not needed for the example but you will obviously need more)

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel">
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <viewModel:YourViewModel x:Key="ViewModel">
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
        <Button Opacity={Binding opValue}>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

YourViewModel.cs

```
namespace ViewModel
{
    class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private float opacity = 1.0f;
        public float opValue
        {
            get { return opacity; }
            private set
            {
                opacity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("opValue");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```